# Select data from three tables having maximo <> 5

Tags: sql

I´m trying to select data from three tables, in table one have id number and timestamp, in table two have id number, quantity and description and in table three have id number and status.

I have next tables:

```
TABLE ordenes
|id_orden|fecha_registro
|   1    |15-Oct-2016 12:00:05
|   2    |15-Oct-2016 12:35:55
|   3    |15-Oct-2016 12:42:20



TABLE pre_ordenes
|id_orden|cantidad|descripcion
|    1   |    1   |cd adele
|    1   |    2   |cd sia
|    2   |    2   |cd rihana
|    2   |    2   |cd rita
|    2   |    2   |cd adele
|    3   |    2   |cd sia
|    3   |    2   |cd rihana
|    3   |    2   |cd adele
|    3   |    2   |cd marhia

TABLE estado_orden/
|id_orden|tipo_estado
|    1   |     1
|    1   |     2
|    1   |     3
|    1   |     4
|    1   |     5
|    2   |     1
|    2   |     2
|    2   |     3
|    2   |     4
|    3   |     1
|    3   |     2
|    3   |     3
```

Hoy can I obtain this?

```
|id_orden|fecha_registro       |cantidad|descripcion
|    2   |15-Oct-2016 12:35:55 |    1   |cd rihana
|    2   |15-Oct-2016 12:35:55 |    1   |cd rita
|    2   |15-Oct-2016 12:35:55 |    1   |cd adele
|    3   |15-Oct-2016 12:42:20 |    1   |cd sia
|    3   |15-Oct-2016 12:42:20 |    1   |cd rihana
|    3   |15-Oct-2016 12:42:20 |    1   |cd adele
|    3   |15-Oct-2016 12:42:20 |    1   |cd marhia
```

This is because id_orden=1 have tipo_estado=5 and id_orden 2 and 3 doesn´t have 5 as tipo_estado

Comment: We don't actually do your work for you here on SO :D. If you are looking for help, post what you have so far and the community will help you.

Comment: I try many sentences but no one works, i don´t want you do my work, Thanks for the advice, next time add sentences even was wrong.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I take it back. Apparently we do your homework here on Stack Overflow! Thanks @Dong

Answer (score 0):

```
    select o.id_orden, o.fecha_registro, p.cantidad, p.descripcion
    from (ordenes o
    left join pre_ordenes p
    on o.id_orden = p.id_orden)
    join estado_orden e
    on o.id_orden = e.id_orden
    where e.tipo_estado <> 5
```

or try the below as alternative

```
    select o.id_orden, o.fecha_registro, p.cantidad, p.descripcion
    from (ordenes o
    left join pre_ordenes p
    on o.id_orden = p.id_orden)
    where o.id_orden in (select e.id_orden
                         from estado_orden e
                         where e.tipo_estado <> 5)
```

Comment: Mark it as answered if it works. I'd be curious if the first one works as well, I added parenthesizes and changed the last left join to be a join

Comment: But i only need ordenes that doesn´t have estado_orden=5 ant the last alternative shows all ordenes :(

Comment: The first one returns one file for each tipo_estado